# TCPDF forcing content to display in single page or extend page height based on content

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I'm new to TCPDF, i'm creating a table (invoice) in html to generate pdf using `writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);` function, and sometimes my table will be long or short based on content i'm passing through `$_POST`.

So when i create a longer table dynamically, a second page will be created to adjust the table length, but i want the whole table in a single page, no matter the pdf size.

I searched for answers regarding changing pdf size based on dynamically generated content, i couldn't find any.

[image]

Comment: Keeping it on a single page implies that you would need to adjust the font size depending on how many invoice lines there are. You would have to create the PDF virtually in your code with a starting font size, determine if it went to a second page, then keep going through the process reducing the font size each time until it fits. A lot of work for little gain IMO. Why not just put the invoice header into the PDF header function and let it be replicated no matter how many pages there are? What do you gain by trying to cram it all onto a single page (that nobody may be able to read)?

Comment: @Dave is for sure correct. In case you have to do what you want, you may adjust the top and bottom margin when generating the TCPDF page to get more space to hold the contents. But in the long run please consider splitting the contents into pages with header on each page.

Comment: well if it was only used for viewing inside the digital devices, i'd be OK with what you guys said, but it'll be printed as a receipt and will be used afterwards.

Comment: I don't think it being printed should make a difference. I've received many multi-page invoices over the years. It is not at all unusual for invoices to span multiple pages. I suggested what I did based on experience. One of the applications I support implied that they would like what you asked for. After showing them how well the details could/would flow to additional pages they understood.

Comment: @Dave Guess ill have to do what you suggested, can i ask how to remove the thin margin line at the top?

Comment: You should probably ask that in a new question that includes the code you are  using. It isn't at all clear what you mean by thin margin line since a margin is just space around the edges of a page and doesn't really involve a line.